# How to increment counter in gnu awk?

Tags: csv, awk, gnu

I want to be able to essentially print the line number along every printed line in the output after scanning and reworking an input csv file. The input csv file is comma separated, here's a sample

```
Timestamp,Email,Name,Year,Make,Model,Car_ID,Judge_ID,Judge_Name,Racer_Turbo,Racer_Supercharged,Racer_Performance,Racer_Horsepower,Car_Overall,Engine_Modifications,Engine_Performance,Engine_Chrome,Engine_Detailing,Engine_Cleanliness,Body_Frame_Undercarriage,Body_Frame_Suspension,Body_Frame_Chrome,Body_Frame_Detailing,Body_Frame_Cleanliness,Mods_Paint,Mods_Body,Mods_Wrap,Mods_Rims,Mods_Interior,Mods_Other,Mods_ICE,Mods_Aftermarket,Mods_WIP,Mods_Overall
8/5/2018 14:10,honoland13@japanpost.jp,Hernando,2015,Acura,TLX,48,J04,Bob,0,0,2,2,4,4,0,2,4,4,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,0,4,4,4,6,2,0,4
8/5/2018 15:11,nlighterness2q@umn.edu,Noel,2015,Jeep,Wrangler,124,J02,Carl,0,6,4,2,4,6,6,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,4,6,6,6,6,6,4,6,4,6
8/5/2018 17:10,eguest47@microsoft.com,Edan,2015,Lexus,Is250,222,J05,Adrian,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,0,0,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4
8/5/2018 17:34,hchilley40@fema.gov,Hieronymus,1993,Honda,Civic eG,207,J06,Aaron,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,0
8/5/2018 14:30,nnowick3d@tuttocitta.it,Nickolas,2016,Ford,Mystang,167,J02,Carl,0,0,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2
8/5/2018 16:12,mdearl39@amazon.co.uk,Martin,2013,Hyundai,Gen coupe,159,J04,Bob,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
8/5/2018 17:00,alynamg@blogtalkradio.com,Aldridge,2009,Infiniti,G37,20,J06,Aaron,2,0,2,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,0,2,0,2
```

What my code currently does is sift through the csv file, and pick out the car_id column, year, make, and model columns. Then it runs through every column from racer_turbo to the last, and for each row it adds up the values in those columns into a total value and prints that along side the other values (id, make, model, etc.). There is also a ranking column that precedes the other 5 when printed. Here is my code below.

```
BEGIN {
  FS = ",";
  OFS = "\t";

  print "Ranking", "Car_ID", "Year", "Make", "Model", "Total";
}
FNR > 1 {
  rank = 0;
  total = 0;

  if(NR > 1) {
    for(i = 8; i < NF; i++) {
      total += $i;
    }
    print ++rank,$7,$4,$5,$6,total;
  }
}
END {

}
```

My current output is as follows

```
Ranking Car_ID  Year    Make    Model   Total
1       48      2015    Acura   TLX     58                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
1       124     2015    Jeep    Wrangler        118                                                                                                                         
1       222     2015    Lexus   Is250   36                                                                                                                                  
1       207     1993    Honda   Civic eG        40                                                                                                                          
1       167     2016    Ford    Mystang 18                                                                                                                                  
1       159     2013    Hyundai Gen coupe       14                                                                                                                          
1       20      2009    Infiniti        G37     36                                                                                                                          
1       178     2009    Honda   Oddesy  66
```

My problem is that under the ranking column, it only shows 1 for each row, I need it to be able to increment starting at 1 and going down for as many lines as there are in the document. Right now as evident in my code, I have a rank variable that acts as a tracker that I want to increment up with each row printed, but it only prints 1 for each row. How can I fix that?

The expected output is this

```
Ranking Car_ID  Year    Make    Model   Total
1       48      2015    Acura   TLX     58                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
2       124     2015    Jeep    Wrangler        118                                                                                                                         
3       222     2015    Lexus   Is250   36                                                                                                                                  
4       207     1993    Honda   Civic eG        40                                                                                                                          
5       167     2016    Ford    Mystang 18                                                                                                                                  
6       159     2013    Hyundai Gen coupe       14                                                                                                                          
7       20      2009    Infiniti        G37     36                                                                                                                          
8       178     2009    Honda   Oddesy  66
```

Please be advised, my machine is running version 4.0.2 of AWK.

Comment: Drop the `rank = 0` line. It resets the variable `rank` to 0 every time.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need own variable in this case, just subtract `1` from `NR` to get desired output, that is

```
BEGIN {
  FS = ",";
  OFS = "\t";

  print "Ranking", "Car_ID", "Year", "Make", "Model", "Total";
}
FNR > 1 {
  total = 0;

  if(NR > 1) {
    for(i = 8; i < NF; i++) {
      total += $i;
    }
    print NR-1,$7,$4,$5,$6,total;
  }
}
```

As side note: `END` is optional, you do not have to have one in GNU `AWK` command.